# How to change the cart subtotal value using observer in magento 2?

Tags: magento2, checkout, cart, custom-prices

I want to change the cart subtotal calculation in magento 2

but i try this code but not changing

```
 $quoteQty = $quote->getQuoteQty();
 $priceOne=$priceOne/$quoteQty;
 $quoteItem->setCustomPrice($priceOne);

 $quoteItem->setOriginalCustomPrice($priceOne);
 quoteItem->setRowTotal(($priceOne/$quoteQty) * $quoteQty); //Here i edited the Cart values
```

setRowTotal()

method not working **how I change the cart subtotal value** and what is the use of `setRowTotal`() ??

Comment: Have you found the solution?

Comment: nope...........................

Comment: how i can change the cart sub total value in my module

Comment: In shopping cart (or) Minicart ?

Comment: what is mini cart

Comment: i need in shopping cart

Comment: https://webkul.com/blog/magento2-set-custom-price-of-product/ check this link

Comment: it's good but i need to change cart sub total price